# tr not displaying border-bottom

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a datagrid and stumbled on two problems.

I had to use border-collapse: separate; to get round corners on top.
But by doing that I lost the ability to add borders on tr botton.

Any insights?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KNb7K/

css:

```
table.dgrid {
    border: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
    .border-radius(8px, 0px, 0px, 8px);
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
table.dgrid th:first-child{
    .border-radius(0px, 0px, 0px, 8px);
}

table.dgrid th:last-child{
    .border-radius(8px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
}

table.dgrid th{
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
table.dgrid tr th:last-child, table.dgrid tr td:last-child{
    border-right: 0px; 
}
table.dgrid tbody tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table.dgrid tr {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
    border-collapse: collapse ;   
}
table.dgrid th, table.dgrid td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
}
```

html:

```
<table class="dgrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ativar</th>
            <th>Imagem</th>
            <th>Posição</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>Excluir</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Apply your borders to the TD elements not the TR elements. That's pretty much the best way to go afaik and it's what I've always done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `bottom-border` on `table.dgrid th, table.dgrid td` and then I would update the `table.dgrid tbody tr:last-child` to have the `td` in there like so: `table.dgrid tbody tr:last-child td`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `border-collapse: separate;` from `table.dgrid`.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
table.dgrid {
    width: 98%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
    margin:1%;
}
table.dgrid th:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
table.dgrid th:first-child, table.dgrid td:first-child{
    border-left: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
}
table.dgrid th:last-child{
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
table.dgrid th{
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
table.dgrid tbody tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table.dgrid th, table.dgrid td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
    border-right: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
}
```

Comment: basically do not use borders on tr elements, I modified the width and margins so that you can see clearer. Basically all td use borders top left and right, while the last bottom row is from the table itself